# Enabling a button in WPF depending on Multiple Conditions(switch case type)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my xaml structure something like this:

1. Radio buttons and corresponding controls that will be enabled if the radio button is selected. For Example, if the radio button food is selected, then two text boxes will be enabled, for the radio button Drinks, a combo box will be enabled.
2. And a Button to process the the data in the dialog.

I want to enable the Button only when one radio button is selected and its corresponding controls are populated. 
I am using a command for the button in my view model. Please help me do this.

### Command for the button

```
    EnableProcessButton = new RelayCommand(ExecuteButton, CanExecuteButton);  
    public ICommand EnableProcessButton
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
    private bool CanExecuteButton(object obj)
    {
        switch (SelectedMode)
        {
            case "Drinks": return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedDrink));
                break;
            case "Food": return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1)) && (text2 != default(int)));//The second text box is implemented as a numeric one
                break;                
            default: return false;
                break;
        }

    }

    private void ExecuteButton(object obj)
    {
        //DO the required things.
    }
```

Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="FoodBox1"  Width="120" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Food, Path=IsChecked}" UndoLimit="5"
                      Text="{Binding textbox1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="Foodbox1_TextChanged"/>

        <TextBox Name="FoodBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Food, Path=IsChecked}" UndoLimit="5"
                MaxLength="5" TextChanged="FoodBox2_TextChanged" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding textbox2,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

 </StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="DrinkOptions" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Drinks, Path=IsChecked}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableDrinks}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDrink}"/>
```

When something is written into the textbox and then removed, the button isn't disabled.There is no problem with the combo box.

Comment: Please show the code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do it

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton Content="Food" x:Name="rdbFood" IsChecked="{Binding IsFoodProperty}" ></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Content="Drinks" x:Name="rdbDrinks" IsChecked="{Binding IsDrinkProperty}"></RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupItem>
    </GroupBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBox1}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=rdbFood, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBox2}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=rdbFood, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"></TextBox>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDrink}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=rdbDrinks, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"></ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding EnableProcessButton}"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT**

View Model

```
    public string SelectedConMode { get; set; }

    private bool? _isFoodProperty;

    public bool? IsFoodProperty
    {
        get { return _isFoodProperty; }
        set
        {
            _isFoodProperty = value;
            if (value != null && (bool)value)
                SelectedConMode = "Food";
        }
    }

    private bool? _isDrinkProperty;

    public bool? IsDrinkProperty
    {
        get { return _isDrinkProperty; }
        set
        {
            _isDrinkProperty = value;
            if (value != null && (bool)value)
                SelectedConMode = "Drinks";
        }
    }


    private string _selectedDrink;

    public string SelectedDrink
    {
        get { return _selectedDrink; }
        set
        {
            _selectedDrink = value;
        }
    }

    private string _textBox1;

    public string TextBox1
    {
        get { return _textBox1; }
        set
        {
            _textBox1 = value;
        }
    }

    private int _textBox2;

    public int TextBox2
    {
        get { return _textBox2; }
        set
        {
            _textBox2 = value;
        }
    }



    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        IsFoodProperty = true;
        IsDrinkProperty = false;
        EnableProcessButton = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteButton(null), () => CanExecuteButton(null));
    }

    public ICommand EnableProcessButton
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
    private bool CanExecuteButton(object obj)
    {
        switch (SelectedConMode)
        {
            case "Drinks":
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedDrink));
            case "Food":
                return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textBox1)) && (_textBox2 != default(int)));
            default:
                return false;
        }

    }

    private void ExecuteButton(object obj)
    {
        //DO the required things.
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already done till this part. I just want the correct logic to enable the button.

Comment: Is the RelayCommand used by you is from MVVMLight framework? The framework takes care of enabling the button automatically once the conditions are met

Comment: Its from the MVVMLight Framework. I have done something similar to this except that i have a command for the radio buttons where the name of the radio button is passed as the parameter and `selectedConMode` is set based on the parameter. The problem I am facing is that, The button is correctly enabled after entering valued in the two textboxes. But after that if i delete value from one textbox, it is not disabled.

Comment: Is it possible to post your xaml so that I can modify the answer as per your current logic

Comment: Just guessing, but I believe you need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your binding of the textboxes

Comment: @Dominik : WPF will take care of updating the values from the UI. The default behaviour for textbox is LostFocus.

Comment: @Sandesh yeah I know, I just suspected that he wants to have the button disabled while typing in the textbox, which doesnt work with the default behavior. So I adviced him to change that.

Comment: Oh. Okay so if he wants realtime behaviour of the change to be reflected then yes as you said he needs to update the source trigger to PropertyChanged. What also confuses me is why is he using Command for radio buttons for the above simple scenario

Comment: I have already set the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Property changed`. Will post the xaml

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't hooked your CanExecuteChanged event to the CommandManager’s RequerySuggested:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
   add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
   remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

And for more information about this, have a look here :

https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/

Comment: Thank you. Will try this. In the meanwhile i found a different way to do this.

Comment: There is a big problem with this, in that RequerySuggested only works when a UI element has changed(mouse/keyboard event) and NOT when something in the ViewModel changes...its a known issue that even Microsoft talks about and doesn't use in their own later implementations of DelegateComand for precisely this reason

Answer (score 0):

I declared two `booleans` in the `viewmodel` which is set in the `TextChanged` event handlers of the two textboxes. And the `CanExecute` function becomes

```
private bool CanExecuteButton(object obj)
{
    switch (SelectedMode)
    {
        case "Drinks": return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedDrink));
            break;
        case "Food": return (enableButtonFoodbox1 && enableButtonFoodbox2);//These two booleans are initialized to false and set to true in the TextChangedEvent Handlers of the two textboxes
            break;                
        default: return false;
            break;
    }

}
```

Now, its working properly. Thanks.